# Unable to generate sitemaps for my website

Tags: sitemap

I had used sitemap on [my website](http://mycampusnotes.com) for a while , so I thought I should update my sitemap, but when I went to any online sitemap generator, sitemap isn't properly generating, its not based on any cms

my current sitemap : http://mycampusnotes.com/sitemap.xml

but I have been using many sitemap generator website, I am getting only these 3 url as output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->

<url>
  <loc>http://mycampusnotes.com/</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://mycampusnotes.com/Default.aspx</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://mycampusnotes.com/privacyPolicy.html</loc>
  <lastmod>2014-07-03T13:23:21+00:00</lastmod>
</url>
</urlset>
```

I haven't changed any permission to any folder, is there some script that is blocking ? or some added files that are blocking the sitemap generation ? I am getting these 3 outputs on every sitemap generator website, **the only change I made is the change in frontpage (main page)**, I changed it completely , so is that the reason for failure of generation of sitemap ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, because your home page contains only 2 outbound internal links:

[image]

Every of these 2 pages also doesn't contain internal links to other pages.

Comment: ohh.. yess, got it, thank you, actually I was using javascript for outbound links which was not detected (converted it back to anchor links and it worked)